# htaccess AddHandler ALL?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, include, addhandler

I'm trying to inject a tracking code to **all** the website files.. after googling for a while a found [a tutorial](http://resurrectionwebdesign.com/tips/injecting-google-analytics-without-changing-files) to do it from *.htaccess* .. this is how it works

```
Options +Includes
AddHandler server-parsed .html
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .html
php_value auto_prepend_file /var/www/to_include.php
php_value auto_append_file /var/www/to_include2.php
```

`to_include.php` has a php `ob_start()` to buffer the page contents and add my code to it, and `to_include2.php` has the `ob_end_flush()` that goes to the end of the page...

That's good till now, but it doesn't apply it to every single file ..

I'm not an htaccess expert but as you see the second and third line where it says

```
AddHandler server-parsed .html
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .html
```

it says only apply it to .php and .html files, How can i use `AddHandler` to handle all kind of files, including apache directories.. it has no extension but i also want some line that does it to every visited page on the website,

My target is to track all kind of moves on the website and inject *google analytics* to each file

Answer (score 0):

What do you need server-parsed files for in this?

Did you try `AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .*` ?

Think of a different solution anyways if it won't work.
`mod_rewrite` might also help, redirect * to your script, ...

.htaccess files usually only apply for its directory and subdirectories, make sure it's in the root dir.